# AIOgram. Передача переменных из message.handler в callback.handler

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Делаю телеграм-бота на aiogram. Не получается передать переменные из message.handler в callback.handler. Использую FSM, в message.handler state = "waiting_for_address".

Алгоритм такой => в message.handler бот отправляет inline_keyboard с кнопкой "Взять" в ГРУППУ. Когда кнопку нажимают, то отсылается callback и бот заходит callback.handler. Состояние (state = "waiting_for_address") сохраняется, но только для пользователя, который использовал бота. Но когда мы нажимаем кнопку, появляется еще один пользователь и для него состояние не задано.
Если я в callback.handler вручную задаю состояние, то бот вовсе перестаёт работать.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно это сделать?

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.waiting_for_address)
async def address_enter(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
        inline_button = InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Взять заказ', callback_data='take')
        inline_keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True, one_time_keyboard=True).add(inline_button)
        address = message.text

        await state.update_data(myTelephone=await getPhone(mydb,message))
        await state.update_data(myAddress=address)
        await state.update_data(myId=message.from_user.id)

        user_data = await state.get_data()

        chatId = '-###'

        await bot.send_message(chatId, text=emoji.emojize(f"❗️ <b>Получен заказ</b> ❗️\nАдрес : <b>{user_data['myAddress']}</b>\nТелефон клиента : <b>{user_data['myTelephone']}</b>"),parse_mode='html',reply_markup = inline_keyboard)
        await message.answer('Ваш заказ передан в службу.\nМы оповестим вас, когда найдется водитель!\nЭто не займет много времени',parse_mode='html')

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: call.data == 'take' )
async def agree_ref_start(query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    if query.data == 'take':
        await query.answer("I am callback!")
        
        await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat.id, message_id=query.message.message_id, text=emoji.emojize(f"✅ <b>Заказ взят</b> ✅\nАдрес : <b>{user_data['myAddress']}</b>\nТелефон клиента : <b>{user_data['myTelephone']}</b>\nЗаказ принял @{query.from_user.username}"),parse_mode='html', reply_markup=None)
        await bot.send_message(user_data['myId'],f"✅Ваш заказ был принят, ожидайте!\nЕсли возникнут проблемы, водитель свяжется с вами по номеру <b>{user_data['myTelephone']}</b>\nid таксиста - {query.from_user.id} ",parse_mode='html')

        await state.finish()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я запутался. Давай по новой. Клиент в ЛС бота пишет свои данные и они отправляются в группу админов. Дальше в группе некий работник принимает этот заказ и ему нужны данные которые вы сохранили в стейт юзера. И так как нажал на кнопку совершенно другой юзер, то он не имеет тех же данных, которые есть в стейте юзера отправившего их?

Если это так, то ваша задача это передать данные которые ввел юзер_1 юзеру_2, который в свою очередь находится в другой группе путем нажатия на инлайн кнопку?

Ну тут есть три варианта:
1-При подаче запроса записывать данные в бд.
2-Хранить в колбекдате, но в теории может не хватить места.
3-хранить в юзерском стейте и потом из него вытаскивать данные.
Самый надёжный 1 вариант, у второго может быть проблема в нехватке места в колбек дате, а третий так вообще есть вариант, что вы у юзера_1 сделаете state.finish() и пропали ваши данные. Если вы на 100% уверены, что сбрасывать стейт вы не будете то можно обратиться к стейту другого юзера и вытащить их примерно так.
`stet_for_user = dp.current_state(user=user_id)` где  dp экземпляр диспатчера

PS. И да, вот такая конструкция абсолютно бессмысленна.

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: call.data == 'take' )
async def agree_ref_start(query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    if query.data == 'take':
```

Вот это `if query.data == 'take':` уберите. Вы ведь уже делаете фильтрацию в хендлере. О а еще можно вот это `lambda call: call.data == 'take'` поменять на короткое это `text='take'`. Его можно и в месседж хендлере использовать, там этот `text` будет браться из `message.text`.
Также считаю более приятной для глаза конструкцию

```
asynd with state.proxy() as data:
    data['myTelephone'] = await getPhone(mydb,message)
    data['myAddress'] = address
    data['myId'] = message.from_user.id
```

вместо этого

```
await state.update_data(myTelephone=await getPhone(mydb,message))
await state.update_data(myAddress=address)
await state.update_data(myId=message.from_user.id)
```

Ну и на последок, не обязательно передавать аргументы в `await query.answer("I am callback!")`, можно оставлять его пустым.

Comment: Добрый вечер! 
Да, вы все верно поняли насчет логики. Хорошо, я заношу данные заказа в бд(номер заказа, адрес, телефон, время), но не могу понять, как обратиться потом к данным в callback_handler. Потому что когда я делал это через переменные(делал запрос к базе данных и нужные значения записывал в переменную), то если два человека делают заказ и они оба висят в админской группе - происходит конфликт переменных при взятие заказа и значения последнего заказа накладываются на значения первого.
И спасибо вам за поправки по коду !

Comment: Не понимаю проблемы. Вы записываете данные в бд и с ними юзер айди пользователя потом этот юзер айди передаёте в колбе дате и после в колбек хендлере по этому айди обращаетесь к бд